# How do I refer to a textbox in the main form while in another form

Tags: vb.net

I'm a newbie in VB.Net and i would like to copy the inputs of the textbox in my main form to another users form. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Communicate by using events.

Answer (score 2):

u can always access it using `<FormId>.<TextboxID>`

`UserFrm.TextBoxId1.Text=MainFrm.textBoxId1.Text`

Answer (score 0):

if the Textbox is defined  Private, change Private to Friend, makes it accessible to all classes in your application